# Sending data to external api url django rest_framework [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
#My views file
class CreateImageInfo(APIView):
    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser, FormParser]
    serializer_class = PostCreateUpload

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +
                   c}
        url = 'https://api.logmeal.es/v2/image/recognition/type/{model_version}'
        file = PostCreateUpload(data=request.FILES)
        if file.is_valid():
            file.save()
            image = file.data['image']
            resp = requests.post(
                url, files={'image': open(image, 'r')}, headers=headers)
            return Response(resp.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)



#Serializer File
class PostCreateUpload(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta():
        model = Identified
        fields = ('timestamp', 'image')

#My Models file-

class Identified(models.Model):
    # name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media', blank=True, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.timestamp
```

** current error coe displaying is "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/images/media/art.onlin_281031686_1095087414692746_398359933098246564_n.jpg'"**

Comment: seems you are trying to use this '/images/xxx/some.jpg' as url, try using 'example.com/images/xxx/some.jpg'

Comment: Thank you, I just tried it but it didn't work since I'm using local host. When I try to change the url  to local host, it automatically adds another slash before the link which makes it invalid